# Redirect to a Specific div on Another Page?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to redirect to a div called #login-box on the page index.php so that it can trigger a jquery login form. What can I add to the code below to do that?

```
header("Location: ".$config['site_url']."index.php");
```

Comment: why not just use index.php#login-box

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
header("Location: ".$config['site_url']."index.php#login-box");
```

Comment: okay didnt work as thought, how do I get the redirect to trigger a jquery popup that is usually activated via button click?

Answer (score 1):

this is my best solution which i had never seen this before. maybe this helpful for you.

below code for the page from that i want to redirect on click a link.

```
<div ><a onclick="myHash()"></a></div>
```

this is to redirect to a new page and send hash through url.

```
     function myHash() {
      $(document).ready(function () {
                
                  window.location.href="contact.html#link"
      });
  }
```

And On new page which i want open and scroll to the specific div.

```
<div id="link"></div>
```

And using url's hash to scroll specific div on new page

```
 $(document).ready(function() {    
    if (window.location.hash) {
           setTimeout(function() {
               $('html, body').scrollTop(0).show();
               $('html, body').animate({
                   scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top
                   }, 1500)
           }, 0);
       }
       
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

A code sample of the page doing the redirection would really help here.  Also remember that `header('Location: .... ')` will only work if you haven't sent any output to the browser yet.  That is to say, that if you have an `echo()` before the `header()` function it will fail to work.

Per [PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.